# neo4j user availability data model

Tags: neo4j

I am having a use case of mapping user availability in neo4j where user can mark his availability on a calendar or some task in which he is going to participate.

How to capture and model this in Neo4j?

The main concern is to limit number of nodes.

I found a blog regarding timeline

http://neo4j.com/blog/modeling-a-multilevel-index-in-neoj4/

Is this data model suitable?

Comment: To make this answerable, ideally you would provide more details about what kinds of availability the user would have, what kinds of tasks you're interested in, how fine grained this is, but then also what you've tried and why it's not working.  Why is the concern the number of nodes?  How many are OK?

Comment: Perhaps this SO question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160307/database-model-for-a-24-7-staff-roster-at-a-casino